# Wrapping stream within a stream - will the wrapped stream be disposed properly?

Tags: c#, stream, dispose, word-wrap

I don't know how to check it, for example:

```
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(someStream))
{
    stream.Write("");
}
```

will this behave like this:

```
using (var stream1 = someStream)
{
    using (var stream2 = new StreamWriter(stream1))
         stream.Write("");
}
```

or if I'd wrap into GZipStream or any other stream... will the first example dispose every underlaying stream?

**Update:**

Finally it hit me - just implemented the Stream class myself:

```
class MyStream : Stream
{
    // fake stream implementation

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("disposing in my class");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStream stream = new MyStream();
        DoSomething(stream);
        stream.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("end of program");
    }

    private static void DoSomething(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside using statement");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("after writing");
    }
}
```

and the result:

```
inside using statement
disposing in my class
after writing
disposing in my class
end of program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling close on the top most stream cascades down and will close them all, but this is not recommended because it's hard to keep tabs on whats open and not. As the other answerer said, use the using blocks religiously.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

No you can't rely on it disposing the underlying stream for any `IDisposable` objects (although in the case of the `StreamWriter` it is documented to do so). In general don't rely on it.

You should use nested using statements.

Comment: downvoter.... why? what i said is correct, you shouldn't *rely* on an object implementing IDisposable calling Dispose on any member/parameter IDisposable objects.

Comment: well it's like saying you can't rely on wrapping class not to crash - what's the point of using a framework that I can't depend on behaving constantly?

Comment: In the case of the classes used in his example it's fine, but if the OP takes that to mean, it's fine for all combinations of IDisposable objects, there will be problems.

Comment: A lot of times it's a good idea to leave the responsibility of disposing of objects passed in as parameters to the caller. In these cases you'd need the nested usings.

Comment: Ok, now that doesn't make _any_ sense. If I wrap my 'someStream' in StreamWriter and then dispose the SW then 'someStream' will be also disposed - that's what you guys say. So how could anyone else (the calling method) use that disposed object again? That would not work...

Comment: In this case what you say is correct, you wouldn't use the disposed object again. I'm saying that in many other cases (different objects implimenting IDisposable), you would.

Comment: sure, I totally agree, but that was just regarding streams

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that all classes within the .net framework accepting a stream in their constructor will dispose it when they are disposed. Certainly anyone else implementing a stream wouldn't be required to do so.

Comment: It was me that downvoted you, and it was because the answer was at the time incorrect. Disposing of a StreamWriter *does* dispose of the underlying stream, contrary to what you stated. You have now edited in some more details, so off with the downvote. In the general sense, I agree that you shouldn't rely on this kind of "feature" since it is almost never done like this, only cases I know of is in these streams, but since the question was *specifically* about streams, the answer was originally incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two concepts here.

The main one is nested using blocks, and in the 2nd sample you are using them correctly.

The second issue is nested/wrapped/linked Disposable classes. In the case of StreamWriter and Stream, the Writer will close the Stream. But you don't want to know that, just use the using pattern.

A small tip, the following alternative layout is easier to read and maintain. When adding GZipStream you will have 3+ nested using blocks.

```
using (var stream1 = File.Create(...))
using (var stream2 = new StreamWriter(stream1))
{    
         stream2.Write("");
}
```

Comment: In general I agree with this, you should avoid "knowledge dependencies", but in this case it is also documented to happen, so it is completely safe to not dispose of the inner stream object.

Comment: @Lasse correct but I tend to avoid it anyway. Except for situations where it is pertinent, like using the stream after the Writer.

Comment: I fully agree with you, I always dispose of things like this as well, even though I "know" that in this particular case it won't matter, I still do it. I don't ever want me, or a fellow developer coming along in my code and thinking "huh, that's odd" just because I felt like "optimizing" out this line of code.

Comment: To be honest it's like the people that don't want to use one-line-blocks under if's, for's etc. If this is expected behaviour, then for me it's more clear if I wrap some stream 3 times in one line then indent 3 times...